# session variable appears to lose value in web.py application over Apache

Tags: apache, session, web.py

I'm creating an application on web.py. I use session variables to store some values. All of these worked perfectly fine in web.py's integrated server. I've now installed flups and configured the app to run on my apache server. The session file gets created. However on every submit (GET and POST), the session variables are initialized to their default values. Any reasons why this could happen??

Adding code:

Initialization

`session = web.session.Session(app, web.session.DiskStore('sessions'), initializer={'valid': 'false')`

Setting the value

`session._initializer['valid']='true'`

The code works for the web.py integrated server.

Comment: Is using flup a requirement or a preference? A lot of people (including myself) use Apache + [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/). Sorry I can't help you with flup, though.

Comment: The first time I ran with my Apache server, it could not find flups. That's why I installed the same. Also a new session is being generated  on every request (confirmed with session id). I realized my Apache version is 2.2. So I am without mod_sessions also. I think my issue would get resolved if I installed mod_sessions. But again I'm having a tough time with that. :(

Comment: After adding web.config.debug = False to my code, I now have one session across requests. But still my session variables are taking the default values on every request. Any ideas??

Comment: Please add the code where your session variables are set.